# Animated series where a boy is transferred to another world by a small white-blue alien while he presses a remote with a stone?

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, animated-series

I watched an animated series between 2006-2010 (maybe).

In this series a boy with bluish hair finds a remote like device with a blue stone on it. When he presses the button a very small alien appears before him. It had a V shape on its head. He talks to the boy and when he presses the button again he gets transferred to another world.

There an alien attacks them and to fight the alien he and the small alien merges together and forms a bigger alien like creature. Later they find other humans who can merge with other small aliens, like a girl with a bee-like alien, and a boy with a red dragon-like alien which have the power of fire. Later the main character meets a dragon-like alien and gets merged with it, which allows them to get a sword.

Comment: Was this animated in 2D (hand-drawn) or 3D (computer-generated)?

Comment: @LogicDictates I think it was computer-generated